# linux qt5 window with setWindowFlags set top cause window to move to second screen

Tags: qt5

When I used setWindowFlags method to set the top of the window, the window moved to the second screen, and the window size changed to the resolution size of the second screen. I monitored the move event

when the screen moved, I set it back, but this method would cause the details to flicker and redraw. Is there any other way to prevent this window movement and redrawing? The goal is to switch back and forth between window top and untop